# how do i get a single loop gif to play on firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

previosly my client hadan swf for their logo, this doesn't show well needless to say. i have made a single loop gif for the customer's animated logo. i want it to play once per page load. it currently plays once ever(if at all)

the web page is on a .net server, so i can't implement php code.

i tried a javascript cachebuster:

```
    <img id="gif_animata" src="images/fca-1.gif" width="550" height="50">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gifSource = $('#gif_animata').attr('src'); //get the source in the var
    $('#gif_animata').attr('src', ""); //erase the source     
    $('#gif_animata').attr('src', gifSource+"?"+new Date().getTime()); //add the date to the source of the image... :-) 
    </script>
```

...i would comment on the question sourced, but i can't comment yet

anyway, it didn't do anything for me. the image name still shows as "fca-1.gif" no change to the name when i load the page, and i can see the javascript when inspecting the source

Comment: Please learn about [code formatting in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). (And how to use a shift-key)

Comment: depends where you are looking. View source will always be only what is sent from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try simply this code

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#gif_animata').attr('src',$('#gif_animata').attr('src'))
        },1)
    }, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="gif_animata" src="http://www.lmpenterprises.co.uk/ekmps/shops/pearl/resources/image/animated-gif-2-f.gif" />
```

this code after 2 seconds set every 1 millisecond the source so it is always the first frame

Comment: with this code it still seems that the browser will not reload the image if someone navigates back to the page.

correction. it appears that the browser will continue playing through the gif when it loads on page 2. if the sequence ends on on any page it will not play again until a hard refresh is performed (ctrl+f5)